# Converting separate month, day and year values into a timestamp

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I have a month value (1-12), day value (1-31), and a year value (2010,2011,2012). I also have a hour value and a minute value.

How can I give this to `strtotime()` in a way it can convert it to a timestamp?

Comment: Anyone with PHP 5.3+ will find the `DateCreateFromFormat` function more flexible and forgiving: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3626128/482115

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given the variables `$year` `$month` `$day` `$hour` `$minute` you can do:

```
strtotime("$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute");
```

Be careful to enclose the variables with `"`, never in this case with `'`.

**UPDATE (thanks to comments of @Clockwork and @Tadeck):**

In case there is a variable `$timeofday` that represents the *time of day* (i.e. AM or PM),
then you can parse it this with:

```
strtotime("$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute$timeofday");
```

that is to say, just attach that variable to the end of the text.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also have a time of day (am/pm), can I just tack it on to the end?

Comment: @Clockwork Try to attach the am/pm to the hour. Something like this: `strtotime("$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute$timeOfDay");`. But it's something I've never tested before.

Comment: @Nicolas I have just tested and including `am` or `pm` at the end works properly (as expected).

Comment: @Clockwork and @Tadeck: I've just updated the answer with your comments.

Answer (score 25):

why convert string to date when you already know year month and date.

use [setDate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate) funtion

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate(2001, 2, 3);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 15):

Is `strtotime` the best tool for this job?  What about [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime)?

```
$time = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide it to function `strtotime()` in many ways, as mentioned in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Some examples include:

```
$your_time = strtotime('12/31/2011 9:59');
$your_time = strtotime('2011-12-31 9:59');
$your_time = strtotime('December 31, 2011 9:59');
```

etc. It really is very flexible.

You can find the list of valid formats [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), and that is (from the "Compound Formats" list in the mentioned documentation) for example:

- `10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700`,
- `2008:08:07 18:11:31`,
- `2008-08-07 18:11:31`,
- `2008-07-01T22:35:17.02`,
- `2008-07-01T22:35:17.03+08:00`,
- `20080701T22:38:07`,
- `20080701T9:38:07`,
- `20080701t223807`,
- `20080701T093807`,
- `2008-7-1T9:3:37`,

(this is really copy of the documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this `strtotime("YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM AM/PM")`:

```
echo date("d F Y h:i:s A", strtotime("2011-06-01 11:15 PM")) . "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
01 June 2011 11:15:00 PM
```

Comment: this is not what he is asking for

Comment: Probably you read something in question that I could not but question is not very clear without any sample input, output.

Comment: he only needs strtotime without date

Comment: @yes123: date function is used for the echo purpose only to print in human readable format :)

Comment: @A Clockwork Orange: Please see my answer for example on using AM/PM as well in the end.

Comment: @anubhava I do not agree with `date function is used for the echo purpose only to print in human readable format :)`.

Comment: @Tadeck: Without date function it will print: `1306984500` for above example. At least for me it is much more readable to see output `01 June 2011 11:15:00 PM` as a verification that strtotime call worked fine.

Comment: @anubhava ok, I misunderstood you - I thought you were talking about the purpose of `date()` _in general_, which would obviously be completely incorrect (as `date()` can be used in converting Unix timestamp for multiple purposes).

Answer (score 0):

`Y-m-d hh:mm` will work

```
echo strtotime('2011-12-14 11:44 am');
```

cit @Pekka :)

Answer (score -3):

```
strtotime($month."-".$day."-".$year)
```