# Convert month,day and year to Unix timestamp

Tags: php, date, time

I'm trying to convert month,day and year to Unix timestamp.

```
<?php
  day = '30' ;
  $month = 'November' ;
  $year = '2016' ;
  $t = date('H:i');
  $quoteDate = strtotime("$year-$month-$day $t");
?>
```

This code gives correct year but wrong day and month.

Comment: Are you sure your post values are correct? Post sample values so we can test it.

Comment: yeah.I checked it.Please check edited question.

Comment: mktime is a more precise way to deal with this, no? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: That is not a valid date format for strtotime to parse

Comment: I got that code from this page 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208484/converting-separate-month-day-and-year-values-into-a-timestamp

Comment: try $time = mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this with `DateTime` instead, which can be massaged to handle that kind of date string

```
$day = '30' ;
  $month = 'November' ;
  $year = '2016' ;
  $t = date('H:i');
  $quoteDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-F-d H:i", "$year-$month-$day $t");
echo $quoteDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can see a demo here https://3v4l.org/adJ5P

Comment: OP wants timestamp, `$quoteDate->getTimestamp();`

Comment: @Federico he can use it to get whatever format he wants once the object is created

Comment: @Machavity how can I convert it to Unix timestamp?

Comment: @ShyamMohan use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), which supports the same formatting as `date`