# strtotime() returns current date with DD.MM.YY input - why?

Tags: php, date, time, format, strtotime

Let's say I got this code:

```
echo "12.07.2016 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.2016"));
echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.16"));
```

which returns this:

```
12.07.2016 - 12.07.2016
12.07.16 - 01.02.2016
```

The first date is formatted correctly, the second line returns the current date though - why does this happen? Is strtotime() not able to handle years in two-digit-format?

EDIT: To clarify, I still want date() to put out the year with 4 digits. It just seems that strtotime() doesn't accept any input with 2 digit years, and returns a timestamp of the current date instead...

Comment: check your local time and settings on the server

Comment: Maybe this page can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626052/strtotime-with-year-in-2-digit-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`
>
> **Timestamp** :-  The optional `timestamp` parameter is an integer **Unix timestamp** that defaults to the **current local time** if a timestamp is
>   not given.
>
> In other words, it defaults to the value of time().

So in your case, in line `echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.16"));`

Format you were suppose to put was **12.07.2016** but you put **12.07.16** which is discarded so it took the **default local date**

> You can do like this to format

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', '12.07.16');
echo $datetime->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally an answer that sheds some light on my problem. But how do I handle this? I've got a CSV file that's filled with dates in dd.mm.yy format, and I want to automatically correct them all to dd.mm.yyyy format. So strtotime() doesn't identify dd.mm.yy format... any alternatives?

Comment: @StrikeAgainst  : yes there is a way ... check my answer... i have edited

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You!

Comment: @StrikeAgainst : thats great !!

Answer (score 1):

The Simple reason Is that You need to take small "y" in the following statement:

```
echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.16"));
```

TO

```
echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.y", strtotime("12.07.16"));
```

Answer (score 0):

y in small return year in 2 digits, so your code can be:

```
echo "12.07.2016 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.2016"));
echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.y", strtotime("12.07.16"));
```

Comment: @StrikeAgainst update this echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.16")); to be y in small

Comment: No. I still want it to put out "12.07.2016". It returns "01.02.2016" instead, which is the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "Y" which is used for YYYY formate.

you should try this code

```
echo "12.07.2016 - ".date("d.m.y", strtotime("12.07.2016"));// for YY format
echo "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.16")); // for YYYY formate
echo $a = date("d-m-Y H:i:s",time()); // for current time stamp
```

Output:

```
12.07.2016 - 12.07.16
12.07.16 - 01.02.2016
01-02-2016 12:16:12
```

Comment: The current timestamp is also not what I need... I want to format "12.07.16" to "12.07.2016". strtotime() won't let met though.

Comment: Then try this code:- echo $a = date("d-m-y H:i:s");

Answer (score 0):

It accepts 2 digit year if it is written in correct way.

**Example :**

```
echo $one = "12.07.2016 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("12.07.2016"));
echo "</br>";
echo $two = "12.07.16 - ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime("16-07-12"));
```